# Unable to get Spinner value when click item

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am here trying display seleted value from dropdown spinner, but my`setOnItemSelectedListener` is not working

My code is as follows:-

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.array.location,list);

                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int pos, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                parent.getContext(),
                                "The color is "
                                        + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I don't see any mistake in your `onItemSelected` method.

Comment: is it showing the values in the spinner..? i mean is the array-adapter bonded properly

Comment: Code is getting proper values from String.xml, but when i supply arraylist , it just not respones to onitemselect

Answer (score 1):

```
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.location,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int pos, long id) {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    parent.getContext(),
                                    "The color is "
                                            + spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        }
                    });
```

Make necessary changes and try the above code.If it not works then change `Charsequence` to `String`.

Comment: thx for replay ,but onItemSelected still not showing Toast message

Comment: is it throwing some kind of exception??

Comment: @user3395433 This is a working solution. Please, check kgandroid's code attentively. I've spent some time trying to make it work. So my solution coinsides with this answer. I tested it on a device.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Employee employee = employees.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
});
```

Comment: employee is a java file which has a setter and getter methods, you need to replace arraylist instead employee.

Comment: Make Arraylist object and get the position for this object after binding in the spinner.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

Comment: yup its not answer i am unable to get my self in side nItemSelected